# zero-length lookbehind regex can't be replaced in atom and isn't recognize in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, atom-editor

```
{
                        file: "http://video.jiuan.org/2016/Sep/F4D.mp4",
                        image: "http://www.jiuan.org/ffmpeg_image.php?file=2016/Sep/F4D.mp4&time=00:00:03&browser=true",
                        skin: "/jwplayer-6.6/six.xml",

                        logo: {
                            file: '/jwplayer-6.6/wptv.png',
                            link: 'http://www.worldpeacreever.tv/'
                        },
                        width: 1150,
                        height: 650
                    }
```

Above is a string, into which I wanna find all the property names(like file,image,etc.) and add double quotes to them, so that I can process it with JSON.

I match all the property names with regex

```
(?<=\s)(\w*\b)(?=:)
```

To test my regex, I put this string in Atom

[image]

The property names are matched and highlighted, but when I try clicking "Replace All", they are not removed as expected. Why is this?

Also, when I try to do the replace in javascript

```
STR.replace(/(?<=\s)(\w*\b)(?=:)/g,"\"$1\"")
```

javascript returns an error saying invalid regular expression. I think maybe javascript has a different regex syntax but I couldn't find any useful information to resolve this problem.

Comment: Really no information? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions, JS regexz does not support lookarounds. You just need capturing here: `(\s)\w+:` and replace with `\1:` or `$1:` if you need to turn `width:`  into `:`

Comment: I reached this page, but I really didn't find anywhere saying that JS regexz doen't support lookarounds. Insteadly, I find the description of special character `?` says it is used in lookahead assertions. What did I miss?

Comment: JS regex does not support lookbehinds, `(?<=...)` and `(?<!...)`, it supports lookaheads (`(?=...)` or `(?!...)`). You do not need the positive lookbehind here anyway since capturing with backreferences is enough.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's a problem in "Atom" application, that replacement doesn't work correctly in this case.
2. As @Wiktor Stribiżew said, **lookbehind is not supported in JavaScript**.

Just use like that in JavaScript:

**Search:** `'/(\s)(\w*\b)(?=:)/'`

**Replacement:** `'$1\"$2\"'`